# Why does this not work for project euler part 2? (Python) project euler instructions included

Tags: python

This script can give me

1. All fibonacci numbers up to 4000000
2. give me the sum of all even numbers up to 4000000.

It can not however satisfy the requirement below and I am wanting to know how to make it do so.

My script:

```
#Problem 2
P2 = 0
fib= 0
f1 = 1
f2 = 0
debugP2 = []
while fib < 4000000:
    fib = f1 + f2
    f2 = f1
    f1 = fib
    if fib % 2 == 0:
        P2 += fib
        debugP2.append(fib)
print(debugP2)
print(fib)
```

The question is:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms.
>     By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four
>    million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to print `P2` not `fib`.

```
#Problem 2
P2 = 0
fib= 0
f1 = 1
f2 = 0
debugP2 = []
while fib < 4000000:
    fib = f1 + f2
    f2 = f1
    f1 = fib
    if fib % 2 == 0:
        P2 += fib
        debugP2.append(fib)
print(P2) # Its not fib
```

**Output**

```
4613732
```

**Edit:** You can shorten your program like this

```
P2, fib, f1, f2 = 0, 0, 1, 0
while fib < 4000000:
    fib, f2 = f1 + f2, f1
    f1 = fib
    if fib % 2 == 0:
        P2 += fib
print(P2) # Its not fib
```

**Output**

```
4613732
```

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I'm going to accept and as soon as I get the reputation up vote it.